# Android webview video to play in mediaplayer

Tags: android, html, video, webview, media-player

I'm currently building an app which shows a content with html tags. The content has a HTML5 video tag which shows video from an external source.

By using webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(), I load the html page. The webview shows the video along with the controls (play, stop, etc.). What I want to do is when I clicked the video, it will fire the android default mediaplayer intent downloading and playing the video source, not playing the video inline with the webview

By which way to achieve this task?

Comment: You have to stream the video online? or download to the device?

Comment: stream. I just need to override the play button in video tag and post the url to android's default media player. how can I do that?

Comment: Just do an intent on click event of tat video tag to android mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://your_video_link), "video/mp4");
```

add permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I know how to open the media player, what I can't do is how to detect the click event on video tag and then open the intent. I've used WebView.HitTestResult to get the tag and the url, but it always returns null when I'm clicking the <video> tag. I'm using android 4.4 to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebViewClient shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to detect the click

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {}
```

Comment: the issue with this is mediaplayer would start peeking url just after page loads so i guess shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will be called immediately.