# Is there a way to play video playing in android webview in local media player?

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-webview

I know that a video, that is being played within a WebView, can be played locally. I just do not know how it can be forced to be played within the local media player of the device.

I tried using onLoadResource and shouldOverrideUrlLoading but failed to get the desired results.

```
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) 

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Check if this link is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873371/android-webview-video-to-play-in-mediaplayer

Comment: I tried the solution but no luck...